# How to simulate the probability of success of basis pursuit?

Tags: cross-validation, simulation, lasso

**For those with access to Martin Wainwright's "High-Dimensional Statistics: a non-asymptotic viewpoint" book:**

I am essentially trying to replicate figures 7.3 and 7.4 of Martin Wainwright's book in a noisy setting, but have encountered issues.

**For those who do not have access to the book:**

I am trying to replicate two figures in said book that show the probability of success of the basis pursuit program

\begin{equation}
\min_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^d}\lVert\theta\rVert_1,\quad \text{such that}\quad \mathbf{X}\theta=y,
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$. However, I wish to replicate these simulations in a noisy setting
\begin{equation}
y=\mathbf{X}\theta+\epsilon,\quad \epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^n
\end{equation}
where an extension of the basis pursuit program is
\begin{equation}
\hat{\theta}\in\arg\min_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^d}\left\{\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-\mathbf{X}\theta\rVert_2^2+\lambda_n\lVert \theta\rVert_1\right\}
\end{equation}
with $\lambda_n$ being a regularization parameter.

These figures have the following captions:

> Probability of basis pursuit success versus the raw sample size $n$ for random design matrices drawn with i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ entries. Each curve corresponds to a different problem size $d\in\{128,256,512\}$ with sparsity $s=[0.1d]$.

The approach or rather the algorithm that I had in mind is as follows:

For $i$ in 5:(maximum sample size considered)

1. Generate a sparse linear model using a random design matrix $\mathbf{X}\sim N(0,\mathbf{I}_{n_i})$, error vector $\epsilon\sim\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$ and a sparse coefficient vector $\theta$.
2. Using LARS and Cross Validation find the regularization parameter $\lambda_{n_i}$.
3. Fit the model using the elected $\lambda_{n_i}$
4. Repeat steps 1 and 3 $B$ times
5. Calculate the percentage of basis pursuit success, by calculating the % of correctly recovered parameters.

next $i$.

My issue is with step 2, considering that CV overestimates error in small samples. Do I have to have $\lambda_n$ fixed? Is my algorithm correct? If not I would be grateful for some suggestions.